# How to ignore SSL error in Qt based TCP server - client application

Tags: qt, ssl, tcp

I am implementing client - server application that uses TCP for communication. I would like to use SSL to improve security, but I need to make it possible for client to connect even to servers with self signed or "not-very-secure" certificates. Right now I created some random test certificate and I am trying to use it on my local machine (both server and client runs there, no server host resolution can be done, it's simply localhost).

I am keep on getting this error on client side:

```
Socket error: The host name did not match any of the valid hosts for this certificate
```

I am trying to suppress this by using this code:

```
    // We don't care about self signed certificates
    QList<QSslError> errors;
    errors << QSslError(QSslError::SelfSignedCertificate);
    errors << QSslError(QSslError::HostNameMismatch);
    ((QSslSocket*)this->socket)->ignoreSslErrors(errors);
    ((QSslSocket*)this->socket)->connectToHostEncrypted(this->hostname, this->port);
```

However it doesn't work, no matter if I use this code before or after connection, it still fails because of the "didn't match" error.

How do I tell the `QSslSocket` "dear socket, I don't care at all if the certificate is self signed or doesn't match the valid host, just connect me please"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I figured it out:

The `ignoreSslErrors` with parameters works only if you specify a certificate in a constructor of the class.

An alternative is a call to `ignoreSslErrors()` without parameters. This function however needs to be called from a Qt slot connected to signal sslErrors. It's not explained why is that required by it doesn't seem to work any other way.

Documentation: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsslsocket.html#ignoreSslErrors-1

Working example

```
void Program::OnSslHandshakeFailure(QList<QSslError> errors)
{
    this->socket->ignoreSslErrors();
}

void Program::Connect()
{
    connect(this->socket, SIGNAL(sslErrors(QList<QSslError>)), this, SLOT(OnSslHandshakeFailure(QList<QSslError>)));
    this->socket->connectToHostEncrypted(this->hostname, this->port);
}
```

Comment: Actually, calling ignore SslErrors from a signal makes sense. There can be failures at multiple times during SSL handshake, and this way you can examine the list of error(s) generated at each stage and decide if you want to continue (by ignoring them) or not.